# Criar tela de Login em tempo de execução

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Como criar dentro de um `ShowMessage` ou `ShowModal` uma mensagem onde o usuário teria que informar o código e senha, ao sair desse *`ShowMessage`* eu consiga pegar essas informações (*código e senha*) para fazer algumas críticas?

Comment: o que você já tem pronto?

Comment: @Tiago, poderia verificar a alguma das respostas solucionam o problema? Se Sim marcar como respondida?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o [InputQuery](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/Vcl.Dialogs.InputQuery) mesmo. Use o help para verificar como funciona com mais detalhes, inclusive com exemplos.
Abaixo eu peguei o exemplo do help e adaptei para responder a sua pergunta. Segue o código:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
    InputQuery('Título da caixa de diálogo', ['Código', #1'Senha:'], ['', ''],
        procedure(const AResult: TModalResult; const AValues: array of string)
        var
            str: string;
        begin
            if AResult = mrOk then
            begin
                ShowMessage('Meu código é: ' + AValues[0]);
                ShowMessage('Minha senha é: ' + AValues[1]);
            end;
        end);
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Dê uma certa forma sim...
Seria por meio do `InputQuery` ou `InputBox`. É verdade que esses recursos só fornecem um campo para preenchimento, porém você pode olhar o código fonte dessas funções e montar a sua, mais ou menos como nesse [link](http://www.devmedia.com.br/forum/inputbox-com-data/355426)